# Data Masking (or generating synthetic data) in DB2, with data dependencies

Tags: sql, oracle, db2, data-masking

I have this requirement at work and would like some suggestions on how to go about this:

I support a group that has some data (DB2) and our group wants the data to be synthetic/devoid of any identifiable data. The problem is some of the data that we have is also joined on the fly with some (DB2) tables of a different group that I have no control over.

In this case how do I go about achieving a certain level of data masking/ synthetic data generation?

An simple, bare-bones example of my scenario is here:

My DB2 data:

Employee Number - Name - Email

My source table (which I do not control):

Employee Number - Name - Address

My system wants to show the address of someone without storing it locally. So now if I just obfuscate data like the employee number and my source of Address does not, then there is no way I can get the Address (the joins won't work).

So is there any way outside of just say performing some basic arithmetic operations and hope to do the same in reverse while joining? It just doesn't sound like a god approach.

Any suggestions?

{apologies for tagging oracle but I would like to hear  as many ideas as possible}

Comment: I don't fully understand.  Some sample data and what you want to mask -- and not mask -- would be helpful.  In my experience, `address` is identifying information, and I wouldn't want that returned in a masked system.  My basic advice, though, is to create local copies of the reference tables and obfuscate the ids so they cannot be used outside your system.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough - I want to be able to mask all the identifying information, including the employee number.

The problem that I'm having is that I can get by with updating "x"s for name etc, for example, "John" can become "Jxxn" but when it comes to joining with a different table that I cannot control the data to, I have a problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the `CREATE MASK` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You could hash the Employee Number. It would hit performance on the join as it could not use an index on the join (unless you get the other team to add an index on the expression)

E.g.

```
 SELECT M.Hashed_Employee_Number
 ,      S.Address
 FROM        SourceTable S
 INNER JOIN  MyTable M
 ON HASH8(S.Employee_Number) = M.Hashed_Employee_Number
```

(and of course there is always the *chance* of a hash collision)